# Python re.findall() purpose in this code

Tags: python, regex, python-2.7

I am currently learning Python and I am trying to decipher the code I found online. The point of the code is to compare the raw string with user input key and if it matches, it returns raw string.

I am having problem trying to understand what does `re.findall()` is doing in this code

So head[0] contains a data string

> ('2016-12-22 06:28:36', u'Kith x New Era K 59FIFTY Cap - Pink',
>   u'http://kithnyc.com/products/kith-x-new-era-59fifty-cap-pink')

Key contains a raw string

> key=r'Nike|Ultra'

```
head = self.data
for k in key:
    print k
    flag=re.findall(k,str(head[0]),flags=re.I)
    print len(flag)
    if len(flag)>4:
        print head[0]
```

From my understanding, the purpose of the code is to loop through key and see if it matches head[0]. If it matches, it returns head[0]. However, it is still returning, head[0]

> ('2016-12-22 06:28:36', u'Kith x New Era K 59FIFTY Cap - Pink',
>   u'http://kithnyc.com/products/kith-x-new-era-59fifty-cap-pink')

even if though it doesn't match.

Comment: There seems to be no `return` statement in the above snippet.

Comment: Sorry I didn't include that. I was testing it out and just did print 'sent' instead. I edited the code now

Comment: I do not think we understand what you need. Maybe you want to just return/print those items in `head` that match the `key` regex?

Comment: If `key = r'Nike|Ultra'` then looping on key will loop on every charcater of the string, maybe try with `key=[r'Nike|Ultra']`

Comment: Yes. It is suppose to print items in head if it match key regex. But this is the code I found online and I am trying to understand why did author decides to do it this way. Or Do I have the wrong idea and this is not author purpose at all?

Comment: @Faibbus, wow thank you so much. That what the problem was. It is now looping through each word rather than character. One more question, what is reason for '|'. Does it signify anything? Is it begin use so that it will try to match either Nike or Ultra?

Comment: `|` is regex syntax for "or" so yes, it will match everything containing either Nike or Ultra

Answer (score 1):

> It is suppose to print items in head if it match key regex.

Use the [following code](https://ideone.com/paXzIC) then:

```
import re
head = ('2016-12-22 06:28:36', 'nike item', 'ultra item', 'Kith x New Era K 59FIFTY Cap - Pink', 'http://kithnyc.com/products/kith-x-new-era-59fifty-cap-pink')
key=r'Nike|Ultra'  # This is a regex pattern, matches `Nike` or `Ultra` 
for s in head:     # Iterate the items in head
    if re.search(key, s, flags=re.I): # Search for a match in each item, case insensitively
        print(s)  # Print if found
```

Output: `nike item` and `ultra item`.

In your code, you loop through  the characters of the pattern with `for k in key:`. With `re.findall`, all non-overlapping matches were searched for that match a single char in `k`, and only `head[0]` was checked, all other items were not considered.